# Google App Engine could not upload the project file

Tags: google-app-engine

I made a change to `backends.py` and I'm trying to upload the project and am getting an error. I have used the rollback command as well but I keep getting the error.

```
 Error 409: --- begin server output ---
 Another transaction by user admin is already in progress for app: s~test-appx, 
 backend: urlstat. That user can undo the transaction with "appcfg backends rollback".
--- end server output ---
```

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: What error does the rollback command give you?

Comment: well it wont give any rollback errors . Um getting the error mentioned above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens on occasion when something terrible happens during a push. If you wait long enough, it will eventually time out and you will be able to update normally again.

The lock is specific to a version of your application. So, if time is short, you can work around this error by pushing to a different version, and then making it the default from the appspot.com dashboard.

The `-V` flag allows you to specify which version to target.

```
appcfg.py -V 2 update ./myapp
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on an "interrupted" update and yes the rollback doesn't help either. What worked for me was to keep updating until the error went away - this isn't a real answer but I don't seem to be able to add comments

Comment: use appcfg.py rollback yourdir/ backendname . this will help

Comment: appcfg.py [options] rollback <app-directory>